# Reusing multiple contexts in Python 'with' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

In Python3 we can use multiple contexts in with statements. But is it possible to enter multiple contexts if they can't be constructed right away in the with statement? Is it possible to do something like this?

```
def files():
    return open('a.txt', 'w'), open('b.txt', 'w')

with files():
    pass
```

Or this:

```
files = open('a.txt', 'w'), open('b.txt', 'w')
with files:
    pass
```

Comment: That's an unsafe pattern - if something goes wrong while opening the second file, the first doesn't get closed. If you give more detail about why you're trying to do this, we can probably give you a better option. (ExitStack is likely to be involved.)

Comment: @user2357112 yeah... was going to suggest having a look at `contextlib.ExitStack` as that's my gut feeling but I'm still not sure what the use case is...

Comment: Is there a way to make it safe, e.g. to replicate the behavior of `with open(...), open()...`. Maybe saving context into variable is not nice, but pattern with a function should be fairy safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def files():
    with open('a.txt', 'w') as f1, open('b.txt', 'w') as f2:
         yield f1,f2
```

maybe?

```
with files() as (f1,f2):
     print(f1,f2)
```

Comment: But then you're returning two closed files.

Comment: Also parentheses around the `f1,f2` in `with files() as f1,f2`, or the precedence isn't going to work the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

An example using `contextlib.ExitStack`:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

def files(stack, *args):
    return [stack.enter_context(open(f, "w")) for f in args]

with ExitStack() as stack:
    f1, f2 = files(stack, "a.txt", "b.txt")
    ...
```

or without the wrapper

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    f1, f2 = [stack.enter_context(open(f, "w")) for f in ["a.txt", "b.txt"]]
    ...
```

However, when you know how many files are to be opened ahead of time (and it's a small number of files), the multiple manager form of the `with` statement as shown in [Joran Beasley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329070/1126841) is simpler.